# best EC2 instance type for a management console of other instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, architecture, aws-sdk

I have an application which requires a strong GPU, and it runs on an EC2 instance of type `p2.xlarge` which is ideal for that kind of tasks. Because the `p2.xlarge` instances are quiet expensive though, I keep them offline and only start them when necessary.

Sometimes I do multiple calculations on 1 instance, and sometimes I even use multiple instances at the same time.

I've written an application in Angular that can visualize the results of these calculations. Which I've only tested in an environment where the angular application is hosted on that same instance.

But since I have multiple instances, it would be ideal to visualize them all on a single webpage. **So that leads me to the diagram below, where a single instance is a like a portal or management console that controls the other instances.**

Now, to get things moving, I would like to setup this front-end server as soon as possible. But there are so many instance types to choose from. **What would be the best instance type for this front-end server for a dashboard / portal that controls other aws instances. The only requirements are:**

- of course it should be able to run a nodejs server (and a minimalistic db for storing logins).
- it should be able to **start/stop other aws instances**.
- it should be able to **communicate to other aws instances** using websockets, and as far as I'm concerned, that shouldn't even really be over the internet, that can be **within the aws network**.

[image: architecture]

Comment: maybe just the cheapest one will do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well ,

> of course it should be able to run a nodejs server (and a minimalistic db for storing logins).

Sounds like you need a small machine .
I would suggest using the T2/T3 family . very cheap and can be configured without bursting limits which gives you all the power you need for a very low price .

> it should be able to start/stop other aws instances.

Not a problem , 
Create an IAM role which have permissions to EC2 and when you
launch your instance , give it that IAM role. 
It will be able to do what ever you grant it to do with the api.

Pay attention to the image you use , 
if you take the Amazon Linux 2 you get the aws-cli preinstalled , 
it's pretty nice .

Read more about IAM roles [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html).

> it should be able to communicate to other aws instances using websockets, and as far as I'm concerned, that shouldn't even really be over the internet, that can be within the aws network.

Just make sure you launch all instances in the **same VPC** .
when machines are in the same vpc they can communicate with each other only with internal ips .

You can create a new VPC like [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/getting-started-ipv4.html)

Or , just use the default one .

after you launch the instance you will
get it's internal IP.

Comment: Great answer :) exactly what I was hoping for. - I know what to do now ;-)